# PL SQL Where Clause with Column/Field name being a datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

Quick question playing with PL SQL it seems that the tables column was named as the data type NUMBER so trying to perform a query fails since the column is being recognized as a datatype instead of a column name. Anyone know how to get around this without modifying the schema?

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for the help yeah the issue was it had to be in quotes and was case sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place it between double quotes and the case of each character must match the case of the corresponding character in the column name exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the column name in double quotes ("column_name")

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping a column name in single or double quotes.

Comment: I think it has to be double quotes.

Comment: Yes, single quotes in SQL are for string literals, double quotes are for delimited identifiers.